# React App - url not found after refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've created web app with create-react-app. Everything worked fine - I run npm run build and put build folder on server. Page works, but after I go to any link and refresh the page, I get The requested URL /nieruchomosci/ was not found on this server.

I have .htaccess with this code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sunstreetinvestment",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "browser-image-compression": "^1.0.9",
    "firebase": "^7.13.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^1.4.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.3.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-slideshow-image": "^1.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.13.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

(I have tried with "homepage": ".")

and I use BrowserRouter.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's because of the nature of your app. It's not server side-rendered so the paths don't actually exist. The routing you are seeing when navigating through your app is being generated as you go by the Javascript

Comment: ok.... do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can redirect user to the entry URL of your app if the `/nieruchomosci` path is not found but that's not frontend related

Answer (score 0):

Simply point all the 404 requests to index.html

index.html will go to the URL correctly in the frontend, rather than do the routing using the server

For example, example.com/hello/world is not configured in your server and it will be 404. just redirect it to index.html which will load the react-router logic. And the react-router can recognize the URL properly and render the correct page

Comment: Can you tell me more about it? I've tried with this code in .htaccess DirectoryIndex index.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://sunstreetinvestment.pl/ - know after refresh I'm sent to homepage

Comment: @OlaKozioł, .htaccess is not familiar to me. However, your question is actually duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?rq=1 and the solution is pretty clear. Just "redirect all the 404 request to index.html"